# WCF XML Post Request Only Partially Loading Object

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, post

I have a WCF Service with a "POST" method that takes in XML and turns it into an object, the problem is only some of the fields are being loaded.

Object Sample:

```
[DataMember, XmlElement(IsNullable = false, Type = typeof(String))]
    public String ClaimKey
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataMember, XmlElement(IsNullable = false, Type = typeof(String))]
    public String VehicleRegistrationNo
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

Input Sample

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    public SalvageInstructionResponse Test(SalvageInstructionRequestHeader Item)
    {
        this._objOutput = new SalvageInstructionResponse(SalvageInstructionResponseStatus.FAILURE, "Test", Item.ToString());
        return this._objOutput;
    }
```

XML Sample:

```
      <ClaimKey>str1234</ClaimKey>
  <VehicleRegistrationNo>str1234</VehicleRegistrationNo>
```

So using the above sample only "VehicleRegistrationNo" is loading but the ClaimKey is null.

The XML and the class are bigger but it's loading about 40% of the properties.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense.  Something is going that you aren't recognizing.  Without seeing more of the data I can't help.  Suggest taking a small part of the xml that you can post that show tag that are loading an not loading.  A well formed xml can only have one root element with children and all you provided were two children with not parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When transferring the object between the server end and the client, you should ensure that the DataContract is consistent. 
IExtensibleDataObject interface is a good choice for maintain the consistency. Both DataMember and IsRequired property have an impact on this issue.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/data-contract-versioning
In addition, Data contract Serializer is constrained of the MaxItemInObjectGraph property. Refer to the following code.

```
<behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
```

Feel free to contact me if there is anything I can help with.

Answer (score 1):

To anyone else who gets stuck on this, it's because the nodes in the XML weren't in alphabetical order and no DataMember(OrderNo) wasn't set. So when it was serializing the object .NET was just doing "The best it could".